# WPF disable rows duplicate in Datagrid using foreach loop

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to check each row in unbound datagrid if cell value equal textbox value then dont add the row

using foreach loop

the problem now is that iam using unbound datagrid and cannot use the ItemSource in the foreach loop
and if i run the code below i got error :
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'MyMasrof' to type 'System.Data.DataRow'.'

here is my code :

```
 private void AddMaterial_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Materials_Lookup.Text == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Choose Item First");
            }
            else
            {
                if (Masrof_Grid.Items.Count > 0)
                {


                    foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in Masrof_Grid.Items)
                    {

                        if (dr["Masrof_Material_Name"].ToString() == StoreName_txt.Text)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Item Already Exist");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MySqlConnection conn2 = new MySqlConnection("DataSource='" + DoSomething.Server_Param + "';UserID='" + DoSomething.Uid_Param + "';Password='" + DoSomething.Password_Param + "';Database='" + DoSomething.Database_Param + "';PORT=3306;CHARSET=utf8");
                            conn2.Open();
                            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
                            MySqlDataReader rd;
                            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                            ds.Clear();
                            cmd.Connection = conn2;

                            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT id FROM Items where Item_Arabic_Name  ='" + Materials_Lookup.Text + "'";
                            rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                            if (rd.Read())
                            {

                                Masrof_Grid.Items.Add(new MyMasrof()
                                {
                                    Masrof_Material_Code = (rd["id"].ToString()),
                                    Masrof_Material_Name = Materials_Lookup.Text,
                                    Masrof_MAterial_QTY = QTY_txt.Text,
                                    Masrof_Material_Store = StoreName_txt.Text,
                                    MAterial_Curr_Balance = CurrBalance_txt.Text

                                });
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Cannot be found");
                            }


                            conn2.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MySqlConnection conn2 = new MySqlConnection("DataSource='" + DoSomething.Server_Param + "';UserID='" + DoSomething.Uid_Param + "';Password='" + DoSomething.Password_Param + "';Database='" + DoSomething.Database_Param + "';PORT=3306;CHARSET=utf8");
                    conn2.Open();
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
                    MySqlDataReader rd;
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                    ds.Clear();
                    cmd.Connection = conn2;

                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT id FROM Items where Item_Arabic_Name  ='" + Materials_Lookup.Text + "'";
                    rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    if (rd.Read())
                    {

                        Masrof_Grid.Items.Add(new MyMasrof()
                        {
                            Masrof_Material_Code = (rd["id"].ToString()),
                            Masrof_Material_Name = Materials_Lookup.Text,
                            Masrof_MAterial_QTY = QTY_txt.Text,
                            Masrof_Material_Store = StoreName_txt.Text,
                            MAterial_Curr_Balance = CurrBalance_txt.Text

                        });
                      //  decimal sum = 0m;
                      //  for (int i = 0; i < Masrof_Grid.Items.Count; i++)
                      //  {
                      //      sum += (decimal.Parse((Masrof_Grid.Columns[7].GetCellContent(Masrof_Grid.Items[i]) as TextBlock).Text));
                      //  }
                      ////  txtSumReal.Text = sum.ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("cannot be found");
                    }


                    conn2.Close();
                }




            }




        }
```

Comment: Are you doing this to filter the datagrid?

Comment: To check If the values already exist before adding new row @Kevin Cook

Comment: Shouldn't that be done at the database level before you add the row? I.E. Inside a stored procedure?

Comment: iam add the values from combobox and textboxes not from database so iam afraid that user may add the same item multible times@Kevin Cook

Comment: So if 2 copies of your program are running and both people happen to select the same items, what happens?  You have to do this at the database level.